# How to seed many files with aria2?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm using aria2 with these aliases:

```
cat .bashrc
alias download='while true; do timeout -s 9 1260 aria2c -j 10 *.torrent --bt-require-crypto=true --lowest-speed-limit=1024 --disable-ipv6=true --seed-time=0 --enable-rpc=false; sleep 5; done'
alias seed='while true; do timeout -s 9 1260 aria2c --bt-require-crypto=true --check-integrity=false --bt-seed-unverified=true --disable-ipv6=true -d . *.torrent --seed-time=99999 --seed-ratio=100.0; sleep 5; done'
```

I use "download" to download .torrent files in a dir, and "seed" for seeding..

**QUESTION:** How can I optimize the seeding alias? Am I using the "best" parameters for seeding? (ex.: I have a few hundred .torrent files in the "seed" dir)

Comment: I installed a vbox winxp and use utorrent instead :D

Comment: it depends on what you put in word "optimize". bandwidth? speed?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeding for 21 minutes in a forever loop. That seems utterly pointless. The option --seed-time=99999 contradicts the timeout (1260). Just seed for 72 hours or forever.

The option --disable-ipv6=true is questionable because why would you not want to connect to ipv6 peers?

These two are questionable: --check-integrity=false --bt-seed-unverified=true because you want to send valid data. I understand why you might want to skip the check, just make sure you're not seeding garbage.

I would start them all in one go with xargs and with the -D option so that they run in the background.

something like:

```
 find /data/seed -name '*.torrent' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P 6 aria2 -D --foo --bar
```

I solved a similar problem for myself with ctorrent a couple of days ago. You can find my results online:

- https://github.com/tox2ik/local-bin/blob/master/seed-finished-in
- https://github.com/tox2ik/local-bin/blob/master/seed-finished

It will verify the torrent once and create a hidden file indicating that it is done.